# Is there any way in hibernate to disable caching for particular Property for Entity class in .hbm file?

Tags: hibernate, caching, hibernate-mapping, clob, hbmxml

Is there any way in hibernate to disable 2nd level caching for particular Property (by provide some ignore caching property) in .hbm file?

For Example,I have TextObject.hbm.xml file as following

```
    <hibernate-mapping default-cascade="save-update" auto-import="false">
        <class name="com.nish.TextObject" table="TEXT_TABLE" schema="SFMFG">
            <cache usage="read-write" />
            <id name="objectId" type="string">
                <column name="OBJECT_ID" length="40" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="text" type="clob">
                <column name="TEXT">
                    <comment>Text</comment>
                </column>
            </property>
            <property name="plainText" type="string">
                <column name="PLAIN_TEXT">
                    <comment>Plain text</comment>
                </column>
            </property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

By Using `<cache usage="read-write" />` I have enabled class level caching .

**Requirement:** : What i want

- If I shoot hibernate query to get `TextObject.text` property then it should not be cached.
- But if I shoot hibernate query to get `TextObject.plainText` then it should be cached.
- In Summary, For few properties which i have configured in .hbm file, caching should be disabled and for few properties which i have not configured, caching should be enabled.

**Reason for the question:**

- Hibernate is not allowed to cache clob values, so while fetching property with `type = 'clob'` caching should must be be disabled but for other cachable properties cashing should be enabled.

**Note :**

- Yes, I can Disable Class level caching by removing  `<cache usage="read-write" />` but that's the last case of remove caching for whole entity class.